# Container BoxDecoration flickering when loading a new image

Tags: flutter, dart, scaffold

I am building a login screen and I tried to add a background image which change every 5sec. The mechanism works but there is a white flickering between image, any idea how to change it to a nice animation like fading ?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) =>
    setState(() {
      _imageIdx = Random().nextInt(Config.splashScreenImageList.length);
    })
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    _imageIdx = Random().nextInt(Config.splashScreenImageList.length);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(Config.splashScreenImageList[_imageIdx]),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Stack(children: [
              //Positioned(left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, child: getLogo()),
              Positioned(
```

`splashScreenImageList` is just a List of String as below:

```
class Config{
  static List<String> splashScreenImageList = [
    "assets/splash/splash_1.jpeg",
    "assets/splash/splash_2.jpeg",
    ...
  ];
}
```

Any idea how to make it nice ?

Thanks

Comment: use [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) for smooth transition between images. In the transitionBuilder use FadeTransition or whatever transition you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use **AnimatedOpacity** widget to fade in the new image and fade out the old image

In your splash screen page, do this.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  int _imageIdx = 0;
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) =>
        setState(() {
          _imageIdx = Random().nextInt(Config.splashScreenImageList.length);
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(Config.splashScreenImageList[_imageIdx]),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Stack(children: [
          Positioned(left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, child: getLogo()),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _imageIdx == 0 ? 0 : 1,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: Image.asset(Config.splashScreenImageList[_imageIdx - 1]),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getLogo() {
    return Image.asset(
      "assets/logo.png",
      width: size.width * 0.3,
    );
  }
}

class Config {
  static List<String> splashScreenImageList = [
    "assets/splash/splash_1.jpeg",
    "assets/splash/splash_2.jpeg",

   your codes continues...
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).